# Problema conversion de tipo 'double' en 'double[]

Tags: c#

Programo habitualmente en VB nivel medio, estoy intentando aprender c #, inicialmente para resolver un ejercicio. La consigna es una clase Estudiante, y construir un método que calcula y devuelve el promedio de las notas del estudiante, donde si no hay notas registradas, devuelve 0 … Y otro método ObtenerPromedios que recibe un array de objetos Estudiante como parámetro y devuelve un array de tipo double con los promedios de cada estudiante. Esto trabado hace horas, al intentar obtener los promedios me sale un error de conversión de tipo 'double' en 'double[]' ... Lo cual seguramente es correcto ... Pero no sé cómo evitarlo. Agradeceré aportes para resolver los 2 métodos, creo estoy cerca, pero no llego … copio abajo lo realizado.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Estudiante
{
private string nombre;
private List<double> notas;
   
public Estudiante(string _nombre)
{
    nombre = _nombre;
    notas = new List<double>();
}

public string GetNombre()
{
    return nombre;
}
public double GetNotas(int indice)
{
    return notas[indice];
}

public void AgregarNota(double nota)
{
    notas.Add(nota);

}

public double[] ObtenerPromedios(List<Estudiante> estudiantes)
{
    double[] array_estudiantes = new double[estudiantes.Count];
    double[] suma2 = new double[estudiantes.Count];

    //double suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            array_estudiantes[i] = GetNotas(i);
            //suma += array_estudiantes[i];

        }

    CalcularPromedio(array_estudiantes);

   // double suma2 = CalcularPromedio(suma, 3);
   //array_estudiantes
    return suma2;
}

//public static double[] CalcularPromedio(double sum, double divide)
public static double[] CalcularPromedio(double[] sum)
{
    double[] suma = new double[0];
    
    double sum1 = sum[0];
    sum1 = sum1 + sum[1];
    sum1 = sum1 + sum[2];

    suma[0] = sum1;
    return suma;
}
}

public class program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Estudiante> estudiantes = new List<Estudiante>();

    Estudiante e1 = new Estudiante("Alex Garcia");
    estudiantes.Add(e1);

    e1.AgregarNota(10.0);
    e1.AgregarNota(9.0);
    e1.AgregarNota(5.0);

    Estudiante e2 = new Estudiante("Alicia Perez");
    estudiantes.Add(e2);

    e2.AgregarNota(8.0);
    e2.AgregarNota(7.0);
    e2.AgregarNota(8.0);

    Estudiante e3 = new Estudiante("Carlos Paz");
    estudiantes.Add(e3);

    e3.AgregarNota(6.0);
    e3.AgregarNota(6.0);
    e3.AgregarNota(10.0);

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine("   Listado detallado de Estudiantes y Notas");
    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");

    Console.WriteLine("Estudiante : " + e1.GetNombre());
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e1.GetNotas(0));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e1.GetNotas(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e1.GetNotas(2));
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("Estudiante : " + e2.GetNombre());
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e2.GetNotas(0));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e2.GetNotas(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e2.GetNotas(2));
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("Estudiante : " + e3.GetNombre());
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e3.GetNotas(0));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e3.GetNotas(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Nota : " + e3.GetNotas(2));
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine("   Listado Estudiantes y Notas - Promedios") ;
    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");

    
    foreach (Estudiante estudiante in estudiantes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.GetNombre() + e1.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes)); 
        Console.WriteLine(e2.GetNombre() + e2.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes));
        Console.WriteLine(e3.GetNombre() + e3.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes));
    }

/*        {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.GetNombre() + e1.GetNotas(0));
        Console.WriteLine(e1.GetNombre() + e1.GetNotas(1));
        Console.WriteLine(e1.GetNombre() + e1.GetNotas(2));
    }

    double[] resultado1 = e1.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes);
    double[] resultado2 = e2.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes);
    double[] resultado3 = e3.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes);
*/        
    /*
    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(resultado1[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado1[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado1[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(resultado2[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado2[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado2[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(resultado3[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado3[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(resultado3[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    */

    Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");

    Console.ReadKey();

}
}
```

Comment: vb y c# som practiva,emte lo mismo com sutiles diferencias... pero la funcion ObtenerPromedios no tiene sentido.... que tiene que hacer?

Comment: si, pero aca me obligan a trabajar con objetos ,,, y tuve algunos problemas con las conversiones, aca casi me funciona pero me da error de desborde. El metodo ObtenerPromedios deberia recibir el arreglo con los estudiantes,  le pide al metodo CalcularPromedios calcular el promedio de las 3 notas de cada estudiante, y luego debo imprimir los 3 estudiantes cada uno con su promedio ..

Comment: La idea es que el calculo lo haga CalcularPromedios, y obtener mande y reciba con el calculo ya listo

Comment: vb tambien era con objetos... bueno.. en ese metodo estas devolviendo un solo varlo, y no un array de valores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno puedo notar que tiene varios errores.
en el método CalcularPromedio realizas el calculo como si las el único numero de notas posibles es de 3, debes tener en cuenta que este numero puede variar. Yo te sugeriria algo como esto:

```
public static double CalcularPromedio (Estudiante estudiante){
    if(estudiante.notas.Count == 0) return 0;
    
    double sumaNotas= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < estudiante.notas.Count; i++){
        sumaNotas += estudiante.notas[i];
    }
    return sumaNotas/estudiante.notas.Count;

}
```

y para el caso de ObtenerPromedios te sugeriria algo asi como:

```
public static double[] ObtenerPromedios(List<Estudiante> estudiantes){
    var promedios = new double[estudiantes.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < estudiantes.Count; i++){
        promedios[i] = CalcularPromedio(estudiantes[i]);
    }
    return promedios;
}
```

para poder imprimir los resultados se puede hecer los siguiente.
en el main después de crear los estudiantes creas un listado de estudiantes agregas los estudiantes que ya se agregaron ya llamas al metodo ObtenerPromedios pasandole como parametro ese listado asi:

````
var estudiantes = new List<Estudiante>{e1,e2,e3};
var promedios = Estudiante.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes );

Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");
Console.WriteLine("   Listado Estudiantes y  - Promedios") ;
Console.WriteLine(" ================================================");

for(int i = 0; i < estudiantes.Count; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(estudiantes[i].GetNombre());
    for(int j = 0; j < estudiantes[i].notas.Count; j++){
        Console.WriteLine($"Nota {i}. {estudiantes[i].notas[j]}")
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"promedio. {promedios[i]}");
}

```
````

Comment: Buenisimo Esteban, es por ahi ... sin errores a la vista ... no lo entiendo del todo, pero lo estoy estudiando. Como podria imprimir en la misma linea desde el main cada alumno y promedio en la consola ?

Comment: No estoy pudiendo o sabiendo llamar al metodo ObtenerPromedios para imprimir la info ..

Comment: porque static? que hace que sea necesario que sean static?

Comment: Hola Esteban, gracias por colaborar!, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.  ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: gbianchi, Esto es para evitar tener que crear una instancia de Estudiante para realizar los caculos. Puedes usar los métodos asi: Estudiante.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes)

Comment: Esteban, esta bien clara tu colaboración, no coincido en absoluto con el comentario, a veces solo codigo incita a pensar y madurar, ese fue el caso. Pense que no , pero pude terminarlo . No me funcionó lo que dices, al ejecutar  sale en la consola :  System.Double[] . Algo referente al tipado , lo cual me complico bastante.

Comment: Tuve que hacer traer el arreglo a uno nuevo q funcionó :
        double[] recibo = Estudiante.ObtenerPromedios(estudiantes);
        Console.WriteLine(e1.GetNombre() + "  :  " + recibo[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(e2.GetNombre() + "  :  " + recibo[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(e3.GetNombre() + "  :  " + recibo[2]);

  Obviamente ... funcionó el 99% y me permitió entender el proceso. Gracias a ti !!

Comment: Hola , me faltó un tema que no estoy pudiendo resolver ,,, la idea es que si un estudiante existe como estudiante, pero no tiene notas ( no se le agrega ningun add a la list ) , retorne 0 y no haya errores. Como seria la forma mas optima o sencilla ?